# Type Error when trying to draw image to html5 canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm simply trying to draw an image using the following code:

```
(function() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

        function resizeCanvas() {
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
                drawStuff(); 
        }
        resizeCanvas();

       var imageObj = new Image();

      imageObj.onload = function() {
        drawStuff();
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';

        function drawStuff() {
           context.drawImage(imageObj, 69, 50);
        }
})();
```

But I'm getting the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Type error

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your resize handler is being triggered before imageObj.onload.

Then resizeCanvas() calls drawStuff which tries to paint a nonexistent image object and crash!

```
    function resizeCanvas() {
    console.log("resize");
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
        if(imageObj){
            drawStuff(); 
        }
    }
    resizeCanvas();
```